# JQuery Super Fish Vertical How to position within a Div floated to left of Wrapper(center aligned; margin:0 auto;)

Tags: jquery, position, css-float, superfish

I will be using multiple instances of Super Fish. How can I customize the positioning of JQuery Super Fish Vertical? would like to position it within a Div floated to left of Wrapper.

Center aligning the Wrapper (`margin:0 auto;`) does not help.
I've even tried applying `margin:0 auto;` to the body but it breaks my layout.

Please Help.

I would love to attach a rough layout of the page as I intend to create. But I can't! 10 reputation points required!!!

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/newbie_ready_to_learn/8kFft/

Comment: make a fiddle here ---> http://jsfiddle.net/ post your layout here